# Convert VB.NET "Shared Widening Operator" to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have converting this method from vb.net to c#:

```
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal items As MyOption()) As MyOptionCollection
   Return New MyOptionCollection(items)
End Operator
```

My complaint is that I do not know what this function can complete.  I also want to think of how it is working.   I find that "Widening Operator" means that when you cast the cast will work but I don't think I have the full meaning.

How can I convert this to c#?  Too can you please send me to where I learn what this does ?

Comment: Have you looked at this with reflector? Decompiled to C#?

Comment: I know to turn into MSIL, but I do not know reflector or have tool that can convert this correct (it does not compile)

Comment: Reflector is very popular and can do this. It is a free download here: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: @Oded thank you this tool is very great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a conversion operator that takes array of `MyOption` references and returns an reference to `MyOptionCollection` object. "Widening" means that using this conversion, you won't lose any data. "Operator" means that it can be called with special syntax.

In C#, `Widening` can be replaced with `implicit` (altough I believe it is not exactly the same). So it'll be:

```
public static implicit operator MyOptionCollection(MyOption[] items)
{
   return new MyOptionCollection(items);
}
```

You can read about conversion operators in C# at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473%28VS.80%29.aspx).

More about widening/narrowing:
When the operator is narrowing, it means that you can possibly lose (some of) your data. Good example is casting from `Int64` to `Int32`. If the value is less than maximal for `Int32`, the cast will succeed and the value will be persisted. But otherwise it will fail.
Contrary, widening operator can't lose any data, i.e. casting from `Int32` to `Int64` - you can always do it safely.

Answer (score 1):

A Widening operator is one that can perform a conversion without losing precision/information. As such, it is one that would be safe to declare in C# as an implicit operator.

So the equivalent in C# would be something like:

```
public static implicit operator MyOptionCollection(MyOption[] items)
{
   return New MyOptionCollection(items);
}
```